# how to do out of tree android builds with gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

One of the most compelling features of cmake is the out-of-tree build paradigm, that enables one to build variants of a project into separate folders thus making it quicker to switch between build configurations.

Is there such a mechanism in android + gradle?  Ideally, not a single file would be created or modified in the source tree.

EDIT - What I mean by out of tree is this:

My source folder looks something like:

```
/work/project/build.gradle
/work/project/src/...
/work/project/res/...
```

When I run **gradle build**, I end up with new folders like:

```
/work/project/.gradle/...
/work/project/build/..
/work/project/res/...
```

I would like to build the project using gradle so that thewe new folders and generated files are in a folder outside of **project** such as:

```
/work/build-project/.gradle/...
/work/build-project/build/..
/work/build-project/res/...
```

Here's a good find as to the philosphy behind it:  http://voices.canonical.com/jussi.pakkanen/2013/04/16/why-you-should-consider-using-separate-build-directories/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add to your root project's `build.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
  buildDir = "/external/path/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"
}
```

Comment: This works for the build directory itself, but I still get a project/.gradle directory during the build (gradle 4.1).

Comment: Yes still get ".grandle" and ".idea"  directories. Seems to be impossible to move them :-(

Answer (score 1):

Trying to specify `allprojects.buildDir` as a relative path would not work properly with modules as it is resolved from the current module.

The trick is to define it like that:

`buildDir = "${rootDir.absolutePath}/../../../bin/Android/${project.name}"`

Answer (score 0):

Android supports building with variants.  Look at the documentation on Gradle builds:

[Building with variants](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html#workBuildVariants)

Comment: Sorry maybe I wasn't clear enough, but how to build variants isn't the question, that's relatively well documented.  Building out of tree is what I'm asking specifically.

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "out of tree"?  Thanks.